# Latex: how to align subcaptions on the top left and caption to the right of the figures

Tags: latex

I am using LaTeX to write a report and I'm going crazy to get a result like

[image: this]

with subcaptions (a), (b), (c) align to the top left of the subfigures and caption on the right of the figure.
I've already tried with `floatrow` and `subcaption`, but I've never obtained the result I want.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{subfig}

\floatsetup[figure]{style=plain,subcapbesideposition=top}
\begin{figure*}
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]
    {\begin{subfloatrow}
            \sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{image1}\label{fig:a}}%
            \sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{image2}\label{fig:b}}%
    \end{subfloatrow}}
{\caption{Two figures}\label{}}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre] so we have some starting point

Comment: I added a minimal reproducible example as you suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here some starting point with the `subcaption` package (the exact dimensions might need some tweaking to nicely align with the surrounding text)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{font={bf,small}, skip=1pt, margin=-0.7cm, singlelinecheck=false}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{.63\textwidth}
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\subcaption{}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\end{subfigure}\par
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\subcaption{}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\end{subfigure}
\end{minipage}
\quad
\begin{minipage}[b]{.3\textwidth}
\caption{some caption with aligns at the bottom}\label{key}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot. Do you know if it is possible to get the same result with the SelfArx documentclass?

Comment: Never heard of that

Comment: Thank you @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz. Whit your help I managed to solve my problem with a little variation. With the particular documentclass I am using (`\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{SelfArx}`) the caption of the figure did not align on the left but it remained on the bottom of the figure. I resolved this problem using `SCfigure` instead of `figure`.

Comment: I have one more question about the solution proposed. How can I put the caption of the figure (e.g. "Figure1") on the top left instead of the bottom left?

Comment: @NicolaDall'Osto Change the `b` option of the minipage